# Raspberry Pi 5 overclocking, multi core performance

Tags: overclocking, pi-5

I have several Raspberry Pi 5's with 8 GB of RAM, and am attempting to use them as payload computers to run some fairly intense software we've designed.

I've overclocked them to 3 GHz without issue, but was curious what they actually benchmarked at compared to the stock clock frequency of 2.4 GHz. I used Geekbench 5 to benchmark them.

Single core performance increases by 12.1% for a 16.4% clock speed increase, and 17.5%, for a 25% clock speed increase.

Multi core performance on the other hand, decreases by 2% at 16.4% increase, and decreases by 4% for a 25% clock speed increase. This is bizarre.

The 4GB version of the Raspberry Pi5 appears to have the opposite effect, and the single core performance looks like it responds better too. According to Geekbench stats online anyway.

Does anyone in the community have an idea as to why this is happening, and have a solution to get more performance out of the 8GB version?

Comment: have you considered getting a better single board computer?

Comment: This is a really silly and unhelpful comment. If you don't know the answer, why are you interacting with it?

Comment: If your question was about overclocking for the sake of "how fast can I go" - sure, my comment is irrelevant. But, you want to overclock because, from what I gather, the pi is not performant enough for your needs - therefore a more performant (and less expensive in many cases) alternative would make sense. I'm sorry if you took the internet default position of "being offended for the sake of being offended" at my practical suggestion

Comment: Do you use a official power supply? I am considering lack of good power... otherwise some system bug, i heard about same issue somewhere, but cannot tell where.

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a silly statement and not at all relevant to the initial question. I mentioned the use case for context and context alone. The question is why does multicore performance decrease when overclocked, and why is this not the case with the 4GB version.

Comment: @JaromandaX from the question it's obviously not a case of whether the pi is performant enough. OP is pointing out a bizarre inconsistency between the 4GB and 8GB Pi 5 models that seems to have no explanation, hence his question.

Comment: @dingo27mobile I did not. Just swapped over to an Anker wart that was also rated for 3A and got better results, then swapped over to a bench-top supply capable of 10A. Did see better improvement in both single core and multi core. 3GHz does seems to be the ceiling though, as 3.1GHz didn't give any additional benefit.

Comment: @BenBird 3GHz seem to be current limit everywhere. Wherever you do power up your pi, try using 5.1V, as i had good experience with it - notice official RPI supply has it too, and they know why. Also from curiosity - did you feed it through GPIO, or USBC?

Comment: I powered both via the GPIO and USBC-PD. Better results through the GPIO as I have much higher current PSU(s)